C# programmatically install/update TLS/SSL Certificate to hosted site
I’m creating a C# Winforms application for maintenance of TLS Certificates using Let’s Encrypt.  Currently after a Certificate is issued updating a website’s Certificate via the hosted environment’s control panel is a manual “Copy & Paste” exercise.  I’d like to automate the manual step.
My knowledge of hosted environments is limited to managing a few sites using cPanel.   Is the automation possible? Does the user need to have “root access" in a “shared” hosted environment?
If automation is possible the only code I’ve found remotely similar in intent is for IIS and execution from within a specific IIS environment (code found here on SO):
        public void RegisterCertificate(string webSiteName, string certificateFilePath, string certificatePassword)
    {
        // USE WMI TO DERIVE THE INSTANCE NAME
        ManagementScope managementScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\MicrosoftIISv2");
        managementScope.Connect();
        ObjectQuery queryObject = new ObjectQuery("SELECT Name FROM IISWebServerSetting WHERE ServerComment = '" + webSiteName + "'");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searchObject = new ManagementObjectSearcher(managementScope, queryObject);
        ManagementObjectCollection instanceNameCollection = searchObject.Get();
        ManagementObject instanceName = (from i in instanceNameCollection.Cast<ManagementObject>() select i).FirstOrDefault();

        // USE IIS CERT OBJ TO IMPORT CERT - THIS IS A COM OBJECT
        var IISCertObj = new CERTOBJLib.IISCertObjClass();
        IISCertObj.InstanceName = instanceName["Name"].ToString();
        IISCertObj.Import(certificateFilePath, certificatePassword, false, true); // OVERWRITE EXISTING
    }

Can the above code be adapted to fit my need (I’m assuming the certificatePassword is a certificate’s private key)? My interpretation of the ManagementScope-ManagementObject block based on MSDN documentation is that its obtaining a site’s certificate location within a Certificate Store (please correct me if I'm wrong). The CERTOBJLib.IISCertObjClass() block needs to be replaced with something that updates the certificate in a Store but I don’t where to start looking for that.
If it cannot be adapted is there some other mechanism typically used to automate certificate Install/update in a “shared” hosted website?

Do you know that it's actually being hosted by IIS? it's unlikely the hosting server has given you enough permissions to be able to do this (and it would usually be a really bad idea if they had). You are going to need to talk to them to find out if they have an API. Who is the actual hosting company?

Does not seem possible most likely a security violation
